# Futuretask doesn't work

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I created a `FutureTask` in an analog way to what is presented in Brian Goetz's book [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) (the code sample can be found [here](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/listings.html), listing [5.12](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/listings/Preloader.java)).

The problem is that the task times out even if given 10 seconds. The task just returns `true` so there shouldn't be a reason for it to happen:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    FutureTask<Boolean> task = new FutureTask<>(new Callable<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            return true;
        }
    });

    System.out.println(task.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
}
```

This code prints:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't executed the task. There will never be a result available. The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html?is-external=true) states

> This class provides a base implementation of `Future`, **with methods to
>   start** and cancel **a computation**, query to see if the computation is
>   complete, and **retrieve the result of the computation**. **The result can
>   only be retrieved when the computation has completed**

Submit the task to an `ExecutorService` to be run asynchronously.

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(task); // ideally shutdown the ExecutorService afterwards
```

or run it synchronously

```
task.run();
```

In the links you've given, I'm assuming the `start()` method which runs the `FutureTask` in a new `Thread` is called before attempting to get the result.

Comment: It makes sense. Any regard to the code from the book? It doesn't hand that task to the executor there.

Comment: The code you linked to passes the `FutureTask` to a `Thread` and then invokes `start()` on that thread, which executes the `FutureTask` (by invoking its `run()` method). That's now how you'd want to run most FutureTasks (a thread executor is usually the way to go), but it works the same way. `submit(task)` above takes the task as a `Runnable`.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply code `task.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`,  state of `FutureTask` will never be changed, and finally `TimeoutException` is throwed.

You may see that in source code of java.util.concurrent.FutureTask 
(see openjdk source http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.java#FutureTask.get%28%29):

```
public V get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
    throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
    return sync.innerGet(unit.toNanos(timeout));
}

// In inner class java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.Sync (extends java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronize)
// and in java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronize:
innerGet(long nanosTimeout) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
    if (!tryAcquireSharedNanos(0, nanosTimeout))
        throw new TimeoutException();
    if (getState() == CANCELLED)
        throw new CancellationException();
    if (exception != null)
        throw new ExecutionException(exception);

    return result;
}

public final boolean tryAcquireSharedNanos(int arg, long nanosTimeout) throws InterruptedException {
    if (Thread.interrupted())
        throw new InterruptedException();
    return tryAcquireShared(arg) >= 0 ||
        doAcquireSharedNanos(arg, nanosTimeout);
}

protected int tryAcquireShared(int ignore) {
    return innerIsDone() ? 1 : -1;
}

boolean innerIsDone() {
    return ranOrCancelled(getState()) && runner == null;
}

private boolean ranOrCancelled(int state) {
    return (state & (RAN | CANCELLED)) != 0;
}
// I know it's difficult :|
private void doAcquireShared(int arg) {
    final Node node = addWaiter(Node.SHARED);
    boolean failed = true;
    try {
        boolean interrupted = false;
        for (;;) {
            final Node p = node.predecessor();
            if (p == head) {
                int r = tryAcquireShared(arg);
                if (r >= 0) {
                    setHeadAndPropagate(node, r);
                    p.next = null; // help GC
                    if (interrupted) selfInterrupt();
                    failed = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (shouldParkAfterFailedAcquire(p, node) && parkAndCheckInterrupt())
                interrupted = true;
        }
    } finally {
        if (failed) cancelAcquire(node);
    }
}
```

Sorry for my English.